# Room BaseDao to include partial update methods

Tags: kotlin, generics, android-room

I'm putting together a BaseDao class for usage within my room database and it's working fine up to a point, however, I'm trying to include methods to allow for partial updates which I'm currently defining individually within each of my entity DAOs.

**Example of what I'm currently doing;**

```kotlin
@Dao
abstract class LocalAppDao : BaseEntityDao<LocalApp>(LOCAL_APP_TABLE) {
    @Update(entity = LocalApp::class)
    abstract suspend fun updateInstalled(installedUpdate: LocalAppInstalledUpdate)

    @Update(entity = LocalApp::class)
    abstract suspend fun updateRemote(remoteUpdate: LocalAppRemoteUpdate)
}
```

I'm doing a dimilar thing in a variety of classes, however, what I'd like to do is something like below;

```kotlin
abstract class BaseEntityDao<T>(private val tableName: String) :
    BaseDao<T>(tableName) where T : BaseEntity {

    @Update(entity = T::class)
    abstract suspend fun update(update: BaseUpdate)
}
```

However this presents the below error `Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.` on the line `@Update(entity = T::class)`.

Is there a way I can achieve what I'm looking to do?

I've tried another suggestion I found on line as below;

```kotlin
abstract class BaseEntityDao<T>(private val tableName: String, private val type: KClass<T>) :
    BaseDao<T>(tableName) where T : BaseEntity {

    @Update(entity = type)
    abstract suspend fun update(update: BaseUpdate)
}
```

But get this error `Type parameter in a class literal is deprecated in an annotation argument` with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that, at least for the convenience methods `@Insert`, `@Delete`, `@Update` and `@Query` is that the underlying code is generated, when compiling/building the project; whilst you are trying to utilise reflection (inspection of a passed class) which is undertaken at runtime.

Hence the first "Use a Class" (aka please tell me what to do rather make some wild guess at what code you want generated), the other message is an attempt to use a deprecated annotation argument and at a guess if suppressed would then result in another "Use a Class".

Perhaps consider the following, a simple class:-

```
@Entity
data class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val fooCol1: String /* etc */
)
```

And a @Dao annotated function:-

```
@Update
    fun updateFoo(foo: Foo)
```

If the Foo class is defined as an entity in the entities parameter in the respective `@Database` annotation e.g. `@Database(entities = [Foo::class ....` then after compiling the project then the generated java (visible from the Android View in android Studio) will have a class that is the same name as the `@Dao` annotated interface (or abstract class) that is the same name but suffixed with `_Impl`.

In that class there will be a method such as:-

```
@Override
public void updateFoo(final Foo foo) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        __updateAdapterOfFoo.handle(foo);
        __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        __db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

along with :-

```
    ....
    this.__updateAdapterOfFoo = new EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter<Foo>(__db) {
        @Override
        @NonNull
        protected String createQuery() {
            return "UPDATE OR ABORT `Foo` SET `id` = ?,`fooCol1` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
        }
```

As can be seen, the table name and the columns are obtained somehow. That somehow is via the annotation processing. The class has to be known in order to obtain the respective identifiers (table and column names).